# Check if referrer exists

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-1.1

In my code, I want to check if a referrer url exists and if the referrer url contains a specific sub string.  I know how to check for the sub string:

```
If( InStr( Request.UrlReferrer.ToString(), "some sub string here" ) > 0 ) Then
```

But I don't know how to check if a referrer exists or not.  No refer exists if the url is entered in manually in the address bar.  So I tried this, but this does not work:

```
If (Not (Request.UrlReferrer.ToString() = "")) And (InStr(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString(), "some sub string here") > 0) Then
```

Anyone know how do check if a referrer exists?

Comment: Don't forget, some firewalls can block the referrer, some browsers allow the user to simply turn it off. So, you should never rely on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your problem is you're using `And` when you should be using `AndAlso`.

`And` is NOT short-circuit. So the runtime will evaluate each side of the `And` anyway, then return `true` if both sides are `true`. So you're probably getting a `NullReferenceException` I guess because you're trying to look if the referrer contains something, when the referrer is null, because you've not used short-circuit evaluation.

Conversely, `AndAlso` is short-circuit and will not bother to evaluate the second half of the statement if the first half is false.

I've never yet found a good, compelling reason to use `And` in VB instead of `AndAlso`.

Anyway this should work for you.

```
If (Not IsNothing(Request.UrlReferrer)) AndAlso Request.UrlReferrer.ToString.Contains("substring") Then
    Dosomething
End If
```

Comment: PS. The equivalent short circuit operator is `OrElse` which I would recommend you ALWAYS use instead of `Or`. It can save precious time if the first half of an `OrElse` is true and the second half has to do a database hit or disk IO or something else timely to evaluate.

Comment: +1 to emphasize to **always use** `AndAlso` and `OrElse` instead of `And` and `Or`. The former were created for compat reasons. Tons of (poorly written) VB6 code existed that relied `And` and `Or` not being short-circuited and changing their definition would have broken too many things when upgrading. That's also why you can still `REM`.

Comment: Also, when working with strings, check `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` and the newer (4.0) `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`

Answer (score 2):

Simply check if it is null or not

```
If Request.UrlReferrer IsNot Nothing Then
  .....do your stuff....

End If
```